# Can't create model on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm starting to learn ruby on rails. the problem that i have is that i don't know why i get there while i want to create model 
this is the command that  i tried
 rails generate model Book

and get this error in my ubuntu 16 terminal

```
/home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:40: warning: Insecure world writable dir /opt in PATH, mode 040777
/home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:148:in `rescue in database_configuration': YAML syntax error occurred while parsing /home/android/ruby Tutorial/library/config/database.yml. Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: (<unknown>): found a tab character that violate intendation while scanning a plain scalar at line 17 column 10 (RuntimeError)
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:131:in `database_configuration'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:122:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `execute_hook'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:324:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:345:in `active_record_configured?'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:263:in `disconnect_database'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:97:in `preload'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

i also tried this

```
rails script/generate model Book
```

and i get this error:

```
/home/android/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:40: warning: Insecure world writable dir /opt in PATH, mode 040777
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'script/generate' (see --tasks)
/home/android/ruby Tutorial/library/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/android/ruby Tutorial/library/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/android/ruby Tutorial/library/bin/spring:14:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

//Edit

I check my database but and also check yamlint website also has error on line 17 but there is no error

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: mysql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
   adapter: mysql
   database: library_development
   username: root
   password: root1234
   host: localhost

test:
   adapter: mysql
   database: library_test
   username: root
   password: root1234
   host: localhost

production:
   adapter: mysql
   database: library_production
   username: root
   password: root1234
   host: localhost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is of your `database.yml` file. You have a `tab space` in the file whereas the `YAML` files doesn't allow that since they are treated differently by different editors and tools. And the indentation is the most critical part to proper interpretation of YAML. So on line 17 fix that. And for a permanent solution keep the settings of your text editor according to that. I use `Sublime` in which on each page I have an option of `Convert Indentation to Spaces` and in its configuration I can set `"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true`.

Regarding the second command you were trying:

```
rails script/generate model Book
```

It belongs to `Rails 2` version. Instead use the new command only:

```
rails generate model Book
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a command for Rails 2 on Rails 5.

To generate a model in Rails 5 you should use:

```
rails generate model Book
```

Comment: The main issue of OP is of `database.yml`. This is an secondary option which he tried.

Comment: Both of the issues are valid. Once database.yml is fixed, they will run in to the error fixed by my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `config/database.yml` is valid using http://www.yamllint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check in your application database file.It is in /config/database.yml.If you dont have the file then you can copy from dtabase.yaml.exemple from same directory.

Answer (score 0):

It is your spacing, it looks like you have 3 spaces instead of 2 in your development, test and production sections.

2 spaces:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

3 spaces:

```
development:
   adapter: mysql
```